# Ubuntu 20.04 with iscsi and nested lvm hangs on shutdown/reboot

Tags: lvm, reboot, iscsi

I have a bit complicated lvmcache setup on nvme+iscsi combination on Ubuntu 20.04 VM.
This VM does boot up flawlessly but stuck at stopping various services, lvm2-monitor.service, umount fs, or sd-sync thread.
Shutdown process stuck at `A stop job is running for LVM2 mirrors, ...`, or start emitting logs to console, like

```
INFO: task lvm:#### blocked for more than 120 seconds.
```

and then print kernel stack trace periodically.

```
# lsblk
NAME                            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
loop5                             7:5    0 31.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/10492
sda                               8:0    0  200G  0 disk
└─remote-data_corig             253:7    0  200G  0 lvm
  └─remote-data                 253:8    0  200G  0 lvm  /data
vda                             252:0    0   40G  0 disk
├─vda1                          252:1    0    1M  0 part
└─vda2                          252:2    0   40G  0 part
  ├─vg-boot                     253:0    0  500M  0 lvm  /boot
  ├─vg-swap                     253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─vg-root                     253:2    0   30G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg-cachepv                  253:3    0    5G  0 lvm
    └─remote-cache_cvol         253:4    0    5G  0 lvm
      ├─remote-cache_cvol-cdata 253:5    0    5G  0 lvm
      │ └─remote-data           253:8    0  200G  0 lvm  /data
      └─remote-cache_cvol-cmeta 253:6    0    8M  0 lvm
        └─remote-data           253:8    0  200G  0 lvm  /data

# pvs
  PV              VG     Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/sda        remote lvm2 a--  <200.00g      0
  /dev/vda2       vg     lvm2 a--   <40.00g 520.00m
  /dev/vg/cachepv remote lvm2 a--    <5.00g      0

# lvs
  LV      VG     Attr       LSize    Pool         Origin       Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  data    remote Cwi-aoC--- <200.00g [cache_cvol] [data_corig] 99.94  12.40           0.00
  boot    vg     -wi-ao----  500.00m                                                    
  cachepv vg     -wi-ao----    5.00g                                                    
  root    vg     -wi-ao----   30.00g                                                    
  swap    vg     -wi-ao----    4.00g
```

where vda is an nvme, sda is an iscsi device.
The lv `vg/cachepv` is used as nested pv and then attached to another vg `remote`.
To achieve nested pv setup, i had changed `scan_lvs = 1` from default `0` in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`.

At this time I use lvmcache on `remote/data`. I have tried uncache and delete lv `remote/cache` but it did not resolve this issue.

On my setup, `vg/root` and `remote/data` are both btrfs volume.
from fstab,

```
/dev/mapper/vg-root / btrfs defaults,noatime,compress=lzo,subvol=@ 0 0
/dev/mapper/vg-boot /boot ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/mapper/remote-data /data btrfs defaults,nofail,_netdev,noatime,compress=zstd:1,subvol=@data 0 0
```

I first thought this was caused by LXD snap holding storage-pool on /data. I have added `Requires=data.mount` to `snap.lxd.activate.service` and `snap.lxd.daemon.service` to deactivate service before umount /data but this issue still persists.

```
Ubuntu 20.04, 5.4.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# lvm version
  LVM version:     2.03.07(2) (2019-11-30)
  Library version: 1.02.167 (2019-11-30)
  Driver version:  4.41.0
```

if anyone has any idea, please let me know.

Thanks.